# What features does Django have that Pylons doesn't?

Tags: python, django, pylons

From what I understand, Pylons is more of a '**bare bones'** framework (where you can choose your ORM and template engine), and Django is a little more rich in nature.

**What exactly are the features/frameworky elements that Django has that Pylons doesn't?**

(other than its own ORM, and its auto-admin page generation)

Answer (score 3):

This question overlaps heavily with "[Pros/Cons of Django vs Pylons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681/)," and I think that part of the answer you're looking for is in [Ben Bangeret's answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681/pros-cons-of-django-vs-pylons/784390#784390).  Pylons addresses a larger problem domain than Django does, so there are web apps that are so nontrivial to build in Django that you might as well not even start.  On the other hand, if you're working on a problem that is within Django's ambit - basically content-management sites - then Django will probably work out well for you.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is Django's scaffolding and auto-admin interface. Both of these allow you to quickly start managing data in the website without having to create lots of views etc.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to ask a question about it on Stackoverflow. Django has over 10,000 tagged questions, Pylon has just under 400.

Comment: Maybe because Django is harder to use? :-)  Statistics on *unanswered* questions relative to total *might* help make (or refute) your point.

Comment: Ah, or the need to ask a question about it on stackoverflow.

Comment: Django is extremely popular among novices because it lets them create some basic apps without having any clue how things work.

The more novices use a framework/library/tool the more questions they ask.